# Resume from Suspend Kills all Processes with External Monitor

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, suspend

When I resume from a suspend with my external monitor connected to my Thinkpad T460p, all previously running applications are gone and I'm presented with a fresh, blank desktop.

First I'm presented with a "standard res" login screen. I log in, the laptop screen flashes multiple times, and I see the desktop on the laptop and external monitor for a second. Then both screens flash again and I'm presented with a "high res" login screen and have to re-enter my password.

This only happens when the external monitor is connected; when it's not connected a resume restores all apps as it should.

This is new behavior. Previously the external monitor wouldn't wake up on resume automatically (I had to manually turn it off / on). Only things I can think of that I did recently was played around with xrandr (to get the monitor to come on via a command) and installed some tlp and associated power management tools.

I'm no expert, but it looks like there's a crash/restart of an X/Wayland session? It's been a while since I've used Linux / X.

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: Are you sure they crashed? Use `alt`+`tab` to quickly see if they are still running.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ideapad z510 with nvidia GeForce 740M GPU using Ubuntu 18.04. In my case the proprietary graphics card drivers were causing this problem. After changing to open source ones suspension works correctly. To try this solution go to *Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers* and select open source graphics card drivers.